# Reading the input from XML formatted string and present it in TreeView format

Tags: c#, xml, treeview, linq-to-xml

I am trying to load an XML formatted string into my GUI using a TreeView control. However, the XML formated string is in proprietary layout.

The XML formatted string structure will look like this:

```
<Response>
    <Data>
     <Settings>
        <Setting>
            <SettingsXml>
               <ScanJobs>
                  <ScanJobsData>
                    <Mailboxes>
                      <Name>user1@abc.com|DB1</Name>
                      <Value>true</Name>
                    </Mailboxes>
                    <Mailboxes>
                      <Name>user2@abc.com|DB1</Name>
                      <Value>true</Name>
                    </Mailboxes>
                    <Mailboxes>
                      <Name>user3@abc.com|DB2</Name>
                      <Value>true</Name>
                    </Mailboxes>
                    <Mailboxes>
                      <Name>user4@abc.com|DB2</Name>
                      <Value>true</Name>
                    </Mailboxes>
                    <Mailboxes>
                      <Name>user5@abc.com|DB3</Name>
                      <Value>true</Name>
                    </Mailboxes>
                    <Mailboxes>
                      <Name>user6@abc.com|DB3</Name>
                      <Value>true</Name>
                    </Mailboxes>
                  </ScanJobsData>
               </ScanJobs>
            </SettingsXml>
        </Setting>
      </Setting>
    </Settings>
  </Data>
</Response>
```

Where inside  tags we have a  and  tags.  tag represents the name of the mailbox appended with Database name to which that mail box belongs. For example- user1@abc.com is the name of the mailbox which is associated with Database having name as DB1. Now I am getting the above xml formatted data in a String not as a XML file.

I'd like the output to be structured in TreeView as follows :

+DB1

- user1@abc.com
- user2@abc.com

+DB2

- user3@abc.com
- user4@abc.com

+DB3

- user5@abc.com
- user6@abc.com

I've been searching the web for the past few hours, and none of the results have helped. Some have come close, but perhaps properties won't show up, or node's names won't display, etc.

I'm writing in c# in Visual Studio 2010. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your <Value> tags are ended with </Name> tags and there's a </Setting> too much on line 36

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TreeView treeview = new TreeView();

// Get all the <Name> elements
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlAsString);
var mailboxNames = doc.Element("Response").Element("Data").Element("Settings").Element("SettingsXml").Element("ScanJobs").Element("ScanJobsData").Elements("Mailboxes").Select(m => m.Element("Name"));

// Extract the email and db in each <Name> element
foreach (var name in mailboxNames)
{
    var namesSplit = name.Value.Split('|');
    var email = namesSplit[0];
    var db = namesSplit[1];

    // Create new db node if it not exists and add the email there
    if (!treeview.Nodes.ContainsKey(db))
    {
        TreeNode[] emails = new TreeNode[] { new TreeNode(email) };
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(db, emails);
        treeview.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
    // If db node already exists, add email to currently existing node
    else
    {
        treeview.Nodes[db].Nodes.Add(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to avoid splitting the same thing multiple times by assigning name.Value.Split('|') to a variable

Comment: You may use 'var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlAsString);' instead loading xml from file, if your xml comes elsewhere, as you stated.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return you sequence of DB `TreeNodes` with mail nodes already added to them:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
// or XDocument.Parse(xml_string);
var nodes = from m in xdoc.Descendants("Mailboxes")
            let name = m.Element("Name").Value.Split('|')
            select new {
                Mail = name[0],
                Db = name[1]
            } into md
            group md by md.Db into g
            select new TreeNode(g.Key, 
                                g.Select(x => new TreeNode(x.Mail)).ToArray());
```

Then simply

```
 treeView.Nodes.AddRange(nodes.ToArray());
```

Comment: I know man, I'm just not at the point where I can crap out queries like that in the blink of an eye :D

Comment: Actually it is possible to avoid anonymous type creation - we can group by `name[1]` and then select mail nodes from `name[0]`, but that would be too match for blink of eye :)

Comment: *nods with sheep-like look on face*